# Redmine: Custom filter field for adding News

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'd like to add a custom filter field to "Add News" page in Redmine,
so that when I add a new news I could select group of users the email should be sent to.

The field itself is a list of Redmine User groups and every user is assigned to at least 1 of them.

Has anybody done this? Any suggestions would be appreciated

I've located the 3 files related to the issue:

- /app/controller/news_controller.rb
- /app/models/news.rb
- /app/views/news/_form.html.erb

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.2.1.stable.11156
  Ruby version                             1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.11
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         MySQL
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

So far I've done only 1 modification in Redmine, which sends added news to all registered users.
File: /app/modelsmailer.rb

### Overview:

[image: http://www.lwks.com/images/custom/redmine_question.png]

EDIT: **Following your advice I moved mailer function to the controller:**

```
  def create
    @news = News.new(:project => @project, :author => User.current)
    @news.safe_attributes = params[:news]
    @news.save_attachments(params[:attachments])

    if @news.save
      #news_added(@news)
      if params[:group]
        mail :to => GroupsUser.find(params[:group][:ids]).joins(:users).select("users.mail").compact,
            :subject => "[#{@news.project.name}] #{l(:label_news)}: #{@news.title}"
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

But I'm getting error: **NameError (uninitialized constant NewsController::GroupsUser):** pointing to line

```
mail :to => GroupsUser.find
```

Comment: I think it's clear what you're trying to do, but less clear what needs to be done to accomplish it. Do you already have groups defined somewhere or do you need help with that? Do you need help with the `View` to show the multi-select box? Or do you just need help with your controller to limit who gets e-mailed?

Comment: Defining these groups it's not a problem, they're based on default Redmine User Groups (database table: groups_users). I just need to  pull out the list from DB, display in view and get controller to filter out these groups before sending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

news_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @news = News.new
  @groups = GroupsUser.all
end
```

news/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= label_tag :group_ids "Groups"
<%= collection_select :group, :ids, @groups, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true %>
```

**Edit:**

I'm going to have to take a few guesses on what your controllers look like, but I'll give you something close.  Based on the mailer function you provided, I'm assuming that was called out of the `create` controller after the `News` was saved. I would call the mail function after that. Something like this:

```
def create
  news = News.new(params[:news]
  if news.save
    news_added(news)
    send_mail_to_groups(params[:group][:ids]) if params[:group]
    redirect_to ...
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The mailing part should be removed from `news_added`

```
def news_added(news)
  redmine_headers 'Project' => news.project.identifier
  @author = news.author
  message_id news
  @news = news
  @news_url = url_for(:controller => 'news', :action => 'show', :id => news)
end
```

in favor of its own new routine:

```
send_mail_to_users_by_group_ids(group_ids)
    # Woo: Sent to all users, despite their email settings
    mail :to => GroupsUser.find(group_ids).joins(:users).select("users.mail").compact,
      :subject => "[#{@news.project.name}] #{l(:label_news)}: #{@news.title}"
end
```

You might want to add a `where` clause to only include active users.

I think that's about right. I'm doing it off the top of my head so there's probably a typo or error or two in there. Hopefully it points you in the right direction though.

Comment: Hi Geoff. Thanks for giving it a go! I've added contents of models/mailer.rb to my question

Comment: Hi again. Following your advice I moved mailer function to the controller. Could you please take a look at the updated question

Comment: Is this a correct Active Record query? 
**.select("users.mail").where("users.status = 1").compact**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the code had been in a mailer. (You had it labeled, but I missed it.) The basic code should probably stay where it was. That could be causing the error you're seeing. I just meant to indicate that the model creation should be separate from the mailing. Yes, the snippet in the comment above looks legal.

Comment: Ok, so I moved the mailer's bit back to mailer.rb model but now I'm getting **NameError (uninitialized constant Mailer::GroupsUser):**

How do I initialize **GroupsUser** from ActiveRecord properly?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Try moving the `find()` to the end. Just before `compact`.

Comment: Thanks Geoff for all your efforts. I'm so close to give up.
http://pastebin.com/Nqba8NJ6 that ends up without any Internal errors (just no emails being sent) if I remove **Mailer.news_added(@news).deliver** from the controller. As it is, I get this error **undefined method `ascii_only?'**

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of my league on that error. Why not go ahead and write a new, more targeted question?